# Including plugin dll in Unity from higher .net version

Tags: unity-game-engine

Current .net framework version of Unity is .net v4.6
Will it allow importing of plugins that target .net v4.7?
And as a more generic (not version based) question.
Does Unity allow importing of dlls built on a higher version than the Unity build support?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

The reason is that the DLL may have used C# feature that is not yet supported in the current version of Unity. It will fail silently or you will get a similar error below:

> The primary reference "The DLL" could not be resolved because it has a
>   higher version "x.x.x.x" than exists in the current target framework.
>   The version found in the current target framework is "x.x.x.x".

You need to recompile the plugin with the-same version of .NET Unity is using or find another plugin with the correct version.